# Set year on syslog events read into logstash read after new year

Tags: ruby, datetime, logstash, logstash-configuration

## Question

When reading syslog events with Logstash, how can one set a proper year where:

1. Syslog events still by default lack the year
2. Logstash processing can be late in processing - logs arriving late, logstash down for maintenance, syslog queue backing up

In short - events can come in un-even order - and all / most lack the year.

The Logstash date filter ***will*** successfully parse a Syslog date, and use the current year by default. This can be wrong.

One constraint: Logs will *never* be from the future, not counting TimeZone +/- 1 day.

How can logic be applied to **logstash** to:

1. Check if a parsed date appears to be in the future?
2. Handle "Feb 29" *if* parsed in the year after the *actual* leap year.

## Date extraction and parsing

I've used the [GROK filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to extract the [`SYSLOGTIMESTAMP`](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/legacy/grok-patterns) from the `message` into a `syslog_timestamp` field.

Then the [Logstash date filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) to parse `syslog_timestamp` into the `@timestamp` field.

```
#
# Map the syslog date into the elasticsearch @timestamp field
#
date {
    match  => ["syslog_timestamp",
               "MMM dd HH:mm:ss",
               "MMM  d HH:mm:ss",
               "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",
               "MMM  d yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
    timezone => "Europe/Oslo"
    target => "@timestamp"
    add_tag  => [ "dated" ]
    tag_on_failure => [ "_dateparsefailure" ]
}
# Check if a localized date filter can read the date.
if "_dateparsefailure" in [tags] {
    date {
        match  => ["syslog_timestamp",
                   "MMM dd HH:mm:ss",
                   "MMM  d HH:mm:ss",
                   "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                   "MMM  d yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
        locale => "no_NO"
        timezone => "Europe/Oslo"
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_tag  => [ "dated" ]
        tag_on_failure => [ "_dateparsefailure_locale" ]
    }
}
```

## Background

We are storing syslog events into Elasticsearch using Logstash. The input comes from a wide variety of servers both of different OS and OS versions, several hundred in total.

On the logstash server the logs are read from file. Servers ship their logs using the standard syslog forwarding protocol.

The *standard* Syslog event *still* only has the month and date in each log, and configuring all servers to also add the year is out of scope for this question.

## Problem

From time to time an event will occur where a servers syslog queue backs up. The queue will then  (mostly) be released after a syslog / or server restart. The patching regime ensures that all servers are booted several times a year, so (most likely) any received events will at most be under a year old.

In addition any delay in processing, such as between 31/12 (December) and 1/1 (January) makes an event *belong* to another year than the year it is processed.

From time to time you also will need to re-read some logs, and then there's the leap year issue of February 29th - 29/02 - "Feb 29".

Examples:

```
May 25 HH:MM:SS
May 27 HH:MM:SS
May 30 HH:MM:SS
May 31 HH:MM:SS
Mai 31 HH:MM:SS  # Localized
```

In sum: Logs may be late, and we need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

More advanced DateTime logic can be done with the [Logstash Ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html).

#### Leap year

29th of February every four years makes "Feb 29" a valid date for the year 2020, but not in 2021.

The date is saved in `syslog_timestamp` and run through the date filters in the Q.

The following Ruby code will:

1. Check if this year is a leap year (probably not since parsing failed)
2. Check if last year was a leap year.

If the date falls outside these checks we can't rightly assume anything else, so this check falls into the "I know and accept the risk."

```rb
#
# Handle old leap syslog messages, typically from the previous year, while in a non-leap-year
# Ruby comes with a price, so don't run it unless the date filter has failed and the date is "Feb 29".
#
if "_dateparsefailure" in [tags] and "_dateparsefailure_locale" in [tags] and [syslog_timestamp] =~ /^Feb 29/ {
    ruby {
        code => "
            today = DateTime.now
            last_year = DateTime.now().prev_year
            if not today.leap? then
                if last_year.leap? then
                    timestamp = last_year.strftime('%Y') + event.get('syslog_timestamp')
                    event.set('[@metadata][fix_leapyear]', LogStash::Timestamp.new(Time.parse(timestamp)))
                end
            end
        "
    }
    #
    # Overwrite the `@timestamp` field if successful and remove the failure tags
    #
    if [@metadata][fix_leapyear] {
        mutate {
            copy => { "[@metadata][fix_leapyear]" => "@timestamp" }
            remove_tag => ["_dateparsefailure", "_dateparsefailure_locale"]
            add_tag => ["dated"]
        }
    }
}
```

#### Date in the future

Dates "in the future" occurs if you get i.e. `Nov 11` in a log parsed after New Year.

This Ruby filter will:

1. Set a `tomorrow` date variable two days in the future (ymmv)
2. Check if the *parsed* event date `@timestamp` is *after* (in the future) `tomorrow`

When reading syslog we assume that logs from the future does not exist. If you run test servers to simulate later dates you must of course adapt to that, but that is outside the scope.

```rb
# Fix Syslog date without YEAR.
# If the date is "in the future" we assume it is really in the past by one year.
#
if ![@metadata][fix_leapyear] {
    ruby {
        code => "
        #
        # Create a Time object for two days from the current time by adding 172800 seconds.
        # Depends on that [event][timestamp] is set before any 'date' filter or use Ruby's `Time.now`
        #
        tomorrow = event.get('[event][timestamp]').time.localtime() + 172800
        #
        # Read the @timestamp set by the 'date' filter
        #
        timestamp = event.get('@timestamp').time.localtime()
        #
        # If the event timestamp is _newer_ than two days from now
        # we assume that this is syslog, and a really old message, and that it is really from
        # last year. We cannot be sure that it is not even older, hence the 'assume'.
        #
        if timestamp > tomorrow then
            if defined?(timestamp.usec_with_frac) then
                new_date = LogStash::Timestamp.new(Time.new(timestamp.year - 1, timestamp.month, timestamp.day, timestamp.hour, timestamp.min, timestamp.sec, timestamp.usec_with_frac)
            else
                new_date = LogStash::Timestamp.new(Time.new(timestamp.year - 1, timestamp.month, timestamp.day, timestamp.hour, timestamp.min, timestamp.sec))
            end
            event.set('@timestamp', new_date)
            event.set('[event][timestamp_datefilter]', timestamp)
        end
        "
    }
}
```

**Caveat**: I'm by no means a Ruby expert, so other answers or comments on how to improve on the Ruby code or logic will be greatly appreciated.

In the hope that this can help or inspire others.